# How to deselect only the star which is clicked and not all the stars in rating component in Reactjs material ui 5(mui5)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

For example: I have clicked on the 3rd star of the rating component but when I click on the 3rd star again, the rating component is removing all of the previous stars, i.e., it's showing 0 stars. How to achieve this: if I click on the 3rd star the second time, it should only remove the 3rd star and show me 2 stars and not 0 stars.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the 3rd star and click it again.

Follow the function of Material UI Rating, it will give you the newValue is null.

Just check if the newValue is null, subtract current value for 1.

For example:

```
<Rating
  name="simple-controlled"
  value={value}
  onChange={(event, newValue) => {
    if (newValue === null) {
      setValue(value - 1);
    } else {
      setValue(newValue);
    }
  }}
/>
```